# Как грамотнее: "в Старом городе Праги" или "в Старом городе в Праге"

Tags: стилистика

Как грамотнее в тексте: *в Старом городе Праги* или *в Старом городе в Праге?*

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать мнения филологов или ссылки на нормы...мне тоже многое,что кажется

Answer (score 2):

Правильнее сказать: **в Старом городе в Праге**. [Старый город в Праге | praga-del.ru](http://www.praga-del.ru/stare-mesto.htm)

Старый город Праги мне кажется некорректным сочетанием: лучше ***город в городе*** чем ***город города.***

Answer (score 0):

*Старый город*  - исторический район Праги. Я думаю, употреблять это название следует так же, как и название любого другого района, например *Сокольники*.

Лучше всего сказать "в пражском Старом городе". По моему, ваши варианты возможны, но  менее "благозвучны". Сравните : в московских Сокольниках, в Сокольниках Москвы, в Сокольниках в Москве.

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать мнения филологов или ссылки на нормы...мне тоже многое,что кажется